# Java stream - groupingBy by a nested list (list in a second order)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following data structure -

List of Students that each holds a lists of States that each holds a list of cities.

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class State {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<City> Cities = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class City {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

I want to get the following.

```
Map<String, Students> citiesIdsToStudensList;
```

I write the following

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> statesToStudentsMap = students.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.getStates().stream())
            .flatMap(state -> state.getCities().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(City::getId, Collectors.mapping(x -> x.getId(), Collectors.toList())));
```

But it doesn't get me the result I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the Stream API, you'll need to flat map twice and map each intermediate student and city into a tuple that is capable of holding the student.

```
Map<Integer, List<Student>> citiesIdsToStudentsList =
    students.stream()
            .flatMap(student -> student.getStates().stream().map(state -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(student, state)))
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().getCities().stream().map(city -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), city)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                entry -> entry.getValue().getId(),
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
            ));
```

However, it would maybe be cleaner to use nested `for` loops here:

```
Map<Integer, List<Student>> citiesIdsToStudentsList = new HashMap<>();
for (Student student : students) {
    for (State state : student.getStates()) {
        for (City city : state.getCities()) {
            citiesIdsToStudentsList.computeIfAbsent(city.getId(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(student);
        }
    }
}
```

This leverages `computeIfAbsent` to populate the map and creates a list of each student with the same city id.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the nested for-loops solution equivalent to: students.forEach(student -> student.getStates().forEach(state -> state.getCities().forEach(city -> citiesIdsToStudentsList.computeIfAbsent(city.getId(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(student)))) ?

Comment: @srborlongan Yes, it will have the same result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Tunaki’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36960449/2711488), you can simplify it as

```
Map<Integer, List<Student>> citiesIdsToStudentsList =
    students.stream()
        .flatMap(student -> student.getStates().stream()
            .flatMap(state -> state.getCities().stream())
            .map(state -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(student, state.getId())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

It utilizes the fact that you are not actually interested in `State` objects, so you can `flatMap` them directly to the desired `City` objects, if you do it right within the first `flatMap` operation. Then, by performing the `State.getId` operation immediately when creating the `Map.Entry`, you can simplify the actual `collect` operation.