# Java 8 Streams - Group by parent property

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following model:

```
public class Employee {
    Set<Position> positions;
}

public class Position {
    Area area;
}
```

and then in my controller I have a `List<Employee>` and I want to get with lambda stream operations a `Map<Area, List<Employee>>` that result of knowing the area of every position of the employee.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: By the fact that your employee could have multiple positions, it seems he could also have multiple areas. Do you want the employee to appear in multiple areas in the final map?

Comment: It's not a problem if appears in multiple areas. But if we can filter that, it would be great

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960226/java-stream-groupingby-by-a-nested-list-list-in-a-second-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999568/java-8-convert-mapinteger-liststring-to-mapstring-listinteger-with

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain a flat association between `Employee`s and `Area`s, which would allow you to collect them into a Map with `groupingBy`.

Here's one way to do it :

```
Map<Area, List<Employeee>> map = 
    empList.stream()
           .flatMap (e-> e.positions
                          .stream() // a Stream<Position> for a single Employee
                          .map(p->Collections.singletonMap(e,p.area)
                                             .entrySet ()
                                             .iterator ()
                                             .next ()))
                          .collect (Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                          Collectors.mapping (Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                                              Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Even after correcting the code in my IDE I get the following error inside the `Collectors.groupingBy()` for `Map.Entry::getKey`: `non static method cannot be referenced from static context`